# CoreData removeFrom vs delete

Tags: swift, core-data, sql-delete

In `CoreData` I have a one to many relationship between `Quote` and `Image`. (One quote can have many images.) I've been using `quote.removeFromImage(image)` when I want to delete an image, and even though it no longer appears in my app, I've noticed that it's still in my persistent store. I believe if I use delete it will be gone for good, but perhaps I'm using removeFrom incorrectly?

```
func deleteImage(imageIndex: Int) {
   let quote = currentQuote //currentQuote was fetched with the context
   let image = currentImageArray[imageIndex]
   quote?.removeFromImages(image)
   coreData.saveContext()
 }
```

Comment: Very useful, thank you. Feel free to answer if you'd like credit. I guess there must be situations when you'd want to keep an object in the store but not a specific relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeFromImages` only deletes the relation between the Quote and the Image objects but both remains in your store. If you delete an image and it has a relation with a quote then that relation will automatically be deleted.